# Collapse buttons based on selected button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button

I have a group of 3 buttons (using Bootstrap). They expand as they are supposed to but I'm trying to figure out how to collapse them when one of the other buttons is selected. Basically only one button (and it's corresponding section) should be open at any given time.

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-xl-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-9">
        <div class="well well-filter col-md-7 col-lg-5 col-xl-5 col-sm-7 col-xs-9">
            <div class="form-group">

                <button href="#All" class="btn btn-primary btn-block active" data-toggle="collapse">All Loans</button>

                <button href="#Submitted" class="btn btn-primary btn-block active" data-toggle="collapse">Date Submitted</button>
                <div id="Submitted" class="collapse">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5" for="submitted">Beginning Date:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7 col-lg-7 col-md-7">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="submit-beg-date" placeholder="Beginning Date">
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5" for="submitted">Ending Date:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7 col-lg-7 col-md-7">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="submit-end-date" placeholder="End Date">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button href="#Funded" class="btn btn-primary btn-block active" data-toggle="collapse">Date Funded</button>
                <div id="Funded" class="collapse">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5" for="funded">Beginning Date:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7 col-lg-7 col-md-7">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="funded-beg-date" placeholder="Beginning Date">
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5" for="funded">Ending Date:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7 col-lg-7 col-md-7">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="funded-end-date" placeholder="End Date">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use Accordion ?

Comment: The main reason I didn't use accordion's is that I've had issues with the css styling on them in other applications. I'm trying to figure out a way to work with my current setup but if it's a no-go I'll have to switch over to the accordions. Just trying to figure out if there's a way around that